# async-await непонятная строка

Tags: javascript, json, async-await

У меня есть задача, в ней есть строка которую я не совсем могу понять, разъясните мне пожалуйста следующее.

```
await (await (await fetch ('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')).json())
```

Я понимаю так: `fetch` это асинхронный запрос, `await` это ожидание выполнения какого-то асинхронного действия. вопрос зачем усложнять написанием `3ех await`?
p.s: 
я проверял так-же работает если убрать один `await`

```
await (await fetch ('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')).json()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы разобраться с одной строкой, ее нужно разбить на несколько:

1. вызов [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), возвращает `Promise`, который разрешается при получении ответа

   ```
   var response = await fetch(...)
   ```
2. вызов [`json`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json), возвращает `Promise`, который разрешается, при чтении тела ответа и разбора его в json

   ```
   var json = await response.json();
   ```
3. `json` - это объект, поэтому нет нужды использовать третий `await`

Answer (score -2):

Рабочий пример

```js
// await используется только в async функциях
(async () => {
  // возвращает https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Response
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  // вызывает метод Response, точнее миксина Body https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Body
  const json = await response.json()
  // json - это все что может быть json: объект, массив, строка, число...
  console.log(json)
})()
```